# Hiding property from Endpoint API

Tags: api, google-app-engine, properties, hide, endpoint

I am using Google App Engine backend and endpoint solution.  I have created a class with several properties that I don't want to expose to the API, so use can't set it.  For example, the Primary key or the "active" status.  How do I hide them?

public class User {

```
public static final String NAME="User";

@PrimaryKey
@Persistent
private String userKey; <------- want to hide this from user

@Persistent
private String email_address; <----- expose this only

@Persistent
private boolean active; <---- want to hide this from user
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
@Persistent
@ApiResourceProperty(ignored = AnnotationBoolean.FALSE)
private String userKey;
```